# How to create a circle div around an image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a logo in CSS where a circle is surrounding a transparent png image.

```
<img id="desired" src="https://via.placeholder.com/550">

img#desired {
  width: 10%;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 80px;
  display: block;
}
```

[image]

This successfully creates what I want it to look like. However, a requirement is that a surrounding div is what is creating the circle, not the image.

This is what i have so far:

```
<div>
  <img id="actual" src="https://via.placeholder.com/550">
</div>

div {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
#actual {
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
}
```

but this creates:

[image]

How can I fix my second implementation to look like the first one?

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qf26Lhe0/

Comment: `#actual` should be an inline block as well, you're also missing a border-radius on the image. Try `border-radius:50%` for a sphere

Comment: that doesn't work, the surrounding div still spans a across the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added two more methods. The method you want, you can use background-color instead of setting a border.

```css
img {
  border: 50px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.background {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/500') center/cover no-repeat;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 50px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

/* THE METHOD YOU WANT */
.img-container {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/500" width="500" height="500" />

<div class="background"></div>

<!-- THE METHOD YOU WANT -->
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500" width="500" height="500" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your second method is perfect! I'm curious if there is a way to set image size through CSS instead of HTML, although if not, that's fine

Comment: Of course, you can set the width & height of the image in CSS instead of html. But setting width & height in html is just an SEO optimization approach. You can both set html width & height and in the other way, you can set the width & height in css. The css will override the html width & height.

Comment: actually, I'm unable to replicate what you did for some reason https://jsfiddle.net/vwu19n2j/

Comment: Your problem was about setting the width & height to the image. https://jsfiddle.net/AmirrezaAmini/j89of5mL/60/

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using grid and setting the height on it and the img so I could use % instead of px, and didn't have the flexbox gutters